# Limit of $\frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)\right]$ using Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I am asked to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)\right].$$

I am trying to invoke the following rule

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sum_{k=1}^n f(x+k \Delta x) \Delta x$$

Where $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$.

So far what I have is that my function $f$ is $f(x)=x^2$ and that $a=1,b=4$. Then I get $$\int_1^4 x^2 dx$$ which is not the correct answer. Can someone help me with where I went wrong? Thanks in advance. Don't necessarily need answer just a hint or someone point out what obvious mistake I am making. Sorry. Also if this is a repeat question I apologize I will take it down, couldn't find one.

Comment: How did you come up with $f$ and $a,b$? it seems to me that $f(x)=x^2-x$ and $a=0,b=3$.

Comment: for $a$ I used the starting point of the series which is at $k=1$, and I used $\Delta x = \frac{(b-a)}{n}$ to find $b$. I figured its $x^2$ as the variables are being squared. @GBA

Comment: wait is it $x^2-x$? I'm more confused lol

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Could you please unaccept my current answer? I need to delete it since it is a duplicate of an old one I didn’t remember. You could accept the other very fine answer and refer to the duplicate for the solution by integral. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of Riemann sum we have

$$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a} {n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+k\cdot\frac {b-a} {n} \right)$$

which in your case leads to

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)\right]=\int_{0} ^{3} x^2-x \, dx$$

Refer also to

- [Perfect understanding of Riemann Sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972643/505767)

Comment: thanks! and thanks for referral, so I was right then it WAS $x^2-x$!! nice ok

Comment: Yes of course and limits are $0$ and $3$.

Comment: Could you explain why they are $0$ and $3$ and not $1$ and $4$? its the only part I still do not get, I mean I get if I have $a$ how to find $b$ but why is $a$ not $1$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame From here $f\left(a+k\cdot\frac {b-a} {n} \right)$, by inspection with the given sum for $f(x)=x^2-x$ we can see that $a=0$.

Comment: ahhhh its $0$ plus , gotcha!

Comment: @user: Alternatively, one can also see that the given limit can be expressed as $3\cdot\int_0^1\left (9x^2-3x\right )\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Yes nice observation! This also a valid choice. Thanks

Comment: @user: You answered an *identical* question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2924457/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks to have pointed it out. I’ll deleted it of course. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Hello from the *rectangle-happy* Anti-Calculus League.

> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)\right].$$

$\sum_{r=1}^n r^2 = \frac{1}{3}n^3 + \frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{6}n.$

$\sum_{r=1}^n r^1 = \frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n.$

---

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (3k)^2 = 9\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = 
\frac{9}{3}n^3 + \frac{9}{2}n^2 + \frac{9}{6}n.$

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{n^2} \times \left[\frac{9}{3}n^3 + \frac{9}{2}n^2 + \frac{9}{6}n\right].$

This equals 
$\displaystyle \frac{9n}{3} + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{6n}.$

---

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (3k) = 3\sum_{k=1}^n k = 
\frac{3}{2}n^2 + \frac{3}{2}n.$

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{3k}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{n} \times \left[\frac{3}{2}n^2 + \frac{3}{2}n\right].$

This equals 
$\displaystyle \frac{3n}{2} + \frac{3}{2}.$

---

Therefore, ignoring the leading factor of $\displaystyle \frac{3}{n}$ and ignoring that you are taking a limit, you have the *intermediate computation* of

$\displaystyle \frac{3n}{2} + 3 + \frac{3}{2n}.$

Applying the leading factor $\displaystyle \frac{3}{n}$ gives

$$\frac{9}{2} + \frac{9}{n} + \frac{9}{2n^2}.\tag1$$

Clearly, when applying the limit, as $n \to \infty$, all but the leftmost term in (1) above go to $0$.

Therefore, the limit is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{9}{2}\right)$.

Comment: thanks!!! I always appreciate an alternative approach however, for this its time sensitive as I am taking GRE subject soon lol @user2661923

Comment: @HossienSahebjame I elaborated in great detail, just for clarity.  In actual fact, my approach, for similar problems, might well be the fastest approach.  This is because, with experience, you will recognize, that with each polynomial representation of a summation, you can **ignore** all but the leftmost term.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame That is, my approach avoids having to waste time carefully associating the summation with a specific integral.  If that association takes you longer than $10$ minutes, then my approach will often be fastest.